# Conditional Aggregation with multiple case and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The query below gives me average of case when QuoteStatusID = 6 but it I am having issues with associating the average by Street column.

**QuoteTable**

| QuoteID | QuoteStateID | ProjectManager_userID | Shipping_AddressID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 12 | 56 |
| 2 | 6 | 12 | 56 |
| 3 | 26 | 12 | 56 |
| 4 | 6 | 12 | 18 |
| 5 | 26 | 12 | 18 |

**Shipping_AddressID**

> 56:  338 Elizabeth St
> 18:  83 East St

```
select [User].UserID, [User].fname, [User].lname,[User].JobTitle, address.Street,
    (select avg(case when QuoteStatusID = 6 then 1.0 else 0 end) as QuoteAccept
    from Quote q
    where ProjectManager_UserID = userId
    ) as AcceptanceRate
from [User] 
join quote on [user].UserID=Quote.ProjectManager_UserID
join Address on quote.Shipping_AddressID=Address.AddressID
where userID in (select distinct ProjectManager_UserID from quote)
order by AcceptanceRate desc;
```

**Current output** 3/5 =0.60

| userid | fname | Lname | Street | AcceptanceRate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Jon | Smith | 338 Elizabeth St | 0.6 |
| 12 | Jon | Smith | 83 East St | 0.6 |

**Desired output** 2/3=0.66  AND 1/2=0.50

| userid | fname | Lname | Street | AcceptanceRate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Jon | Smith | 338 Elizabeth St | 0.66 |
| 12 | Jon | Smith | 83 East St. | 0.50 |

Comment: Its much easier to assist if you provide DDL+DML.

Comment: absolutely, one sec

Comment: I tried group by but it was not working as expected. Sorry for the delay, I was trying to figure out how to generate scripts with data. Currently only letting me generate table scripts but no data..

Comment: You just have to type in what you have shown above... rather than us typing it in (since its you that wants assistance) :)

Comment: Right, sorry about that Dale, I will keep in mind next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you don't need a sub-query. Just `avg` as part of the query you have and use `group by` to give you distinct users and addresses.

```
select U.UserID, U.fname, U.lname, U.JobTitle, A.Street
    , avg(case when Q1.QuoteStatusID = 6 then 1.0 else 0 end) as QuoteAccept
from [User] U 
inner join Quote Q on Q.ProjectManager_UserID = U.UserID
inner join [Address] A on A.AddressID = Q.Shipping_AddressID
group by U.UserID, U.fname, U.lname, U.JobTitle, A.Street
order by AcceptanceRate desc;
```

Note: Short aliases make a query more readable. And you don't need your `where` clause, since the join on `Quote` already ensures the same condition.

Comment: Thanks Dale, this Worked as expected! :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you simply amend your avg to be

```
select avg(case when QuoteStateID = 6 then 1.0 else 0 end) over(partition by Shipping_AddressId) as QuoteAccept
```

**Edit**
To still use as a subquery it will need correlating in the where clause on `Shipping_AddressId` also

Comment: Hey this worked but when incorporating in my query I got error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. But thank you for your answer, I see what you did

Comment: @NebelzCheez Without a subquery, in the main part

Comment: Ah ok. The perils of not acutally having the data to play with ;-) This is because of the partition it's now returning a row for each addressId. it needs additional correlation. I'll edit above